# Creating and adding items to list JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, insert, addition

Im trying to create and add strings to a list

```
package the.arraylist.pkgclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 A class to implement a Polynomial as a list of terms, where each term has
 an integer coefficient and a nonnegative integer exponent

 @author your name
 */
public
        class Polynomial
{
// instance variable declarations go here
Term theTerm ; //initializes a term

/**
 Creates a new Polynomial object with no terms
 */
public
        Polynomial ()
{
  // TO DO: Write constructor body here

    ArrayList<Term> list1 = new ArrayList<> ();
}

/**
 Inserts a new term into its proper place in a Polynomial

 @param coeff the coefficient of the new term
 @param expo  the exponent of the new term
 */
public
        void insert ( int coeff , int expo )
{
  // TO DO: write method body here.  
}
```

I don't feel I've initiated the list correctly because I can't call on the list in the **insert** class.

The strings will consist of polynomials which are already strings.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "The strings will consist of polynomials which are already strings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your list as an attribute of your `Polynomial` class so you can add items to it later on.

```
public class Polynomial {

private List<Term> list;

public Polynomial() {
  this.list = new ArrayList<> ();
}

public void insert ( int coeff , int expo ) {
  this.list.add(...);
}
```

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you very much. Everything seems to work now.